# Which vista services can be disabled without problems?

Tags: windows-vista, services, windows-services

I use Vista on a HP pavilion DV2 laptop. When I look through all the services my laptop starts, it really seems there's way too much of it. I multi boot with XP and 7. Both startup in 40 seconds. Vista takes FIVE minutes and FIFTEEN seconds!

Is there some software that can determine which services I don't need? On 7, there's no propietary HP stuff at all, yet it seems to run fine. 
There's a LOT of them and some just sit there doing nothing, monitoring for updates I don't really need or want or need to know about the second they're available.

My laptop is the only computer I use at home, there's no home network, aside from the modem-router, which is cabled, not wifi.

Hope this question is specific enough.

I've looked at the other questions but they didn't answer me.

***Soooo, which services can I delete without problems??
Which services strike you as bloat ware, right of the bat?***

EDIT:
At the moment, I got 77 services on **Automatic**, 10 **Auto Delayed**, 57 **Manual** & 19 **Disabled**. Grand total 152! Seems excessive, no?

Comment: Check this out if you haven't already: [How to speed up boot process under Windows Vista or Windows 7](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140262-how-to-speed-up-boot-process-under-windows-vista-or-windows-7/)

Comment: You don't need to edit "Solved" into your question title, that's what the green "accepted answer" tick is for, and it will show a green bar on the number of answers on the front page to show it is accepted.  Welcome to the site!  Glad you got a working solution.

Comment: instead of disabling services, capture a xbootmgr trace to see WHAT in detail is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8BQdD985KpbMmFpQk5obERaRzQ/edit?usp=sharing

During my research into this, I found this somewhere. It's machine translated, so .... 
But it's a great resource.

Soooo, some services were **"gonna get *gót*"**, and based on  other resource and on Black Viper I eliminated these (48 outta 152 ... well, it aint bad.):

```
Adobe Acrobat Update Service
Application Experience
Base Filtering Engine
Bluetooth Support-service
Bonjour-service
Desktop Window Manager Session Manager
Diagnostic Policy Service
Distributed Link Tracking Client
Function Discovery Provider Host
Function Discovery Resource Publication
Hola Internet Acceleration Updater
HP Health Check Service
Human Interface Device Access
Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)
IP Helper
KtmRm for Distributed Transaction Coordinator
Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v2.0.50727_X86
Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service
Parental Controls
Portable Device Enumerator-service
Ralink Registry Writer
ReadyBoost
Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
Remote Registry
Routing and Remote Access
Secondary Logon
Security Center
Server
Shell Hardware Detection
Tablet PC Input-service
Telephony
Terminal Services
Themes
UPnP Device Host
WebClient
Windows Defender
Windows Firewall
Windows Media Center Extender-service
Windows Media Center Receiver-service
Windows Media Center Scheduler-service
Windows Media Center Service Launcher
Windows Media Player Network Sharing-service
Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
Windows Search
WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery-service
WLAN Auto Config
Workstation
```

EDIT: I can happily report that my boot time went down from 5m35 to 2m51, almost half. That's from multi boot menu to "HDD stops spinning".

Comment: by disabling ReadyBoost you made your system even **SLOWER**. ReadyBoost hosts the Boot Prefetcher *d'oh*

Answer (score 1):

See [Black Viper’s Windows Vista Service Pack 2 Service Configurations](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-vista-service-pack-2-service-configurations/)

Windows services are listed in a table with the following columns:

- DEFAULT ~ What Bill G. thinks should be running on Windows Vista.
- “Safe” Configuration ~ This is the configuration that 95% of the people will be able to use with little or no side effects. It will also minimizes the amount of “errors” that is reported in the Event Viewer. This does notguarantee it will work for you, but if adjusting your services scares you, this configuration would be a good starting point.
- “Tweaked” ~ This is the configuration that I have developed to reduce the “Safe” services started, but maintain system security. This does not guarantee it will work for you.
  asterisk.
      This configuration is a system that is still able to perform many LAN networking functions, such as file and print sharing and uses wireless networking (laptop) plus leaves several security related “features” like the Windows Defender, Windows Firewall and Windows Update active.
      This configuration is not for a Windows Media Center PC. In this case, use “Safe”.
- “Bare-bones” ~ WARNING!!~ This configuration disables many built in features of Windows Vista as well as several security features.

Comment: Wow, that Black Viper thing looks very impressive, I will look at it.